# INSERT ALL - report which insert cause exception

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I have to find any way to report broken insert in **INSERT ALL** clause. 
I need know about what line exactly is invalid and insert it into special log table. 
Is possible to do this? 

I'm trying wrote trigger on table before and after insert but it not working if any exception is throwed.
Another idea is write procedure which convert **INSERT ALL** to single **INSERT**s and executes it in loop, after this catch exception, but I have a troubles with realization of this idea.

Comment: Please pause code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the DML error logging clause

```
INSERT INTO dw_empl
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date, salary, department_id 
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date > sysdate - 7
LOG ERRORS INTO err_empl ('daily_load') REJECT LIMIT 25
```

Full details here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables004.htm

Comment: i see here one problem, i need to create error table for each table i have in system?

Comment: and another question: is it usable with insert all clause?

Answer (score 0):

here is one more option
save exceptions with "save exceptions" clause

```
  forall i in v_data_list.first .. v_data_list.last save exceptions
    insert into original_table values v_data_list (i);
```

and then iterate through saved exceptions

```
  exception
      when others then
        if sqlcode = -24381 then
          for indx in 1 .. sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop
            Pkg_log_err.log_error(p_Sqlcode => sql%bulk_exceptions(indx).error_code,
                                  p_Sqlerrm => sqlerrm(-sql%bulk_exceptions(indx).error_code));
          end loop;
```